# How to investigate runtime Linux Kernel warning

Tags: linux-kernel

My device is running a software based on Linux Kernel 2.6.32.
There was an occurrence of Kernel warning as follow:

```
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"------------[ cut here ]------------"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"WARNING: at net/sched/sch_generic.c:255 dev_watchdog+0x144/0x224()"
INFORMATIONAL,Aug 27 21:55:09,"NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth1 (cdc_ether): transmit queue 0 timed out"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"Modules linked in: GobiSerial GobiNet g_ether leddrv cryptr_micro gpio_event_drv [last unloaded: wlan]"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0a7b518>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xdc) from [<c0a9cfb0>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x48/0x60)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0a9cfb0>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x48/0x60) from [<c0a9d000>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x24/0x30)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0a9d000>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x24/0x30) from [<c0ccae98>] (dev_watchdog+0x144/0x224)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0ccae98>] (dev_watchdog+0x144/0x224) from [<c0aa56a8>] (run_timer_softirq+0x138/0x1b4)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0aa56a8>] (run_timer_softirq+0x138/0x1b4) from [<c0aa1a60>] (__do_softirq+0x70/0xf4)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0aa1a60>] (__do_softirq+0x70/0xf4) from [<c0aa1b24>] (irq_exit+0x40/0x8c)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0aa1b24>] (irq_exit+0x40/0x8c) from [<c0a75070>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x70/0x8c)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0a75070>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x70/0x8c) from [<c0a75a70>] (__irq_svc+0x30/0x80)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"Exception stack(0xc0ed7f80 to 0xc0ed7fc8)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"7f80: 00000000 40000013 00712778 00003505 c0ed6000 c0f11f1c c0a6d3f4 c0ed9bd8"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"7fa0: 80027104 411fc087 0000001f 00000000 c0edb8e0 c0ed7fc8 c0a85cc4 c0a864a4"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"7fc0: 60000013 ffffffff"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0a75a70>] (__irq_svc+0x30/0x80) from [<c0a864a4>] (omap3_pm_idle+0x48/0x4c)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0a864a4>] (omap3_pm_idle+0x48/0x4c) from [<c0a773e4>] (cpu_idle+0x48/0x88)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0a773e4>] (cpu_idle+0x48/0x88) from [<c0008a68>] (start_kernel+0x234/0x28c)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"[<c0008a68>] (start_kernel+0x234/0x28c) from [<80008034>] (0x80008034)"
WARNING,Aug 27 21:55:09,"---[ end trace 7fe9ba4a7fb84cb4 ]---"
```

It does not occur often, but when it does the modules connected to eth1 do not work properly and only device reboot helps.

What is the procedure to investigated such a Kernel issue, or to find an eventual patch(es) related to this in later Kernel versions?

Thanks.

Comment: What system and kernel you are running? Have you ever consider it may be caused by a hardware problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you may run newer kernel on OMAP3. Is it possible in your case?

Comment: Unfortunately running newer kernel is a real revolution in the code and is not possible at short term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general procedure as kernel debugging is a very wide topic. In your case, however, you have a warning that points to the exact code line where it is printed - `net/sched/sch_generic.c` line 255. You should start by reading this line of code and understanding what this actually means and why this could happen. The next step could be to add some debugging prints to this code or crash kernel and so some post mortem analysis on the memory dump.

In your case, it looks like it's a watchdog function that runs from time to time and checks if your device is performing well. I would guess that your card just stopped working and this warning indicates just that. It does not seem like kernel can be blamed here (but it is possible).

Comment: The "warn_slowpath"  trace occurs in the (possibly innocent) victim thread which has been blocked.  The cause is due to some code (or hardware in this case) which blocks the victim from executing.  In general, the best way to debug this is to dump the stacks of all threads when this error occurs to find which one is the cause.